# Comparing 2 lists and printing the differences

Tags: python, html, database, list

I am trying to compare 2 different lists and find the differences between them. Say for example I have `list 1` which consists of `cat,dog,whale,hamster` and list 2 which consists of `dog,whale,hamster`. How would I compare these two and then assign a variable to the difference which in this case is `cat`. Order does not matter however if there is more than one difference each of these differences should be assigned to an individual variable.

*In my actual code im comparing html which consists of thousands of lines so I would prefer something as fast as possible but any is appreciated :)*

Comment: you need to be more precise about what you mean by "difference". E.g. does order matter? If `list` were `['whale', 'cat','hamster','dog']` would the answer be the same?

Comment: If there are multiple values as difference, are you expecting multiple variables to assign each variable to a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists can contain duplicates or if you need to know the elements that are only in one of the two lists, you can use Counter (from the collections module):

```
list1 = ['cat','dog','whale','hamster','dog']
list2 = ['dog','whale','hamster','cow','horse']

from collections import Counter

c1,c2 = Counter(list1),Counter(list2)
differences = [*((c1-c2)+(c2-c1)).elements()]

print(differences) # ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = 'cat,dog,whale,hamster'
str2 = 'dog,whale,hamster'
```

Change strings into python sets:

```
set1 = set(str1.split(','))
set2 = set(str2.split(','))
```

Get the difference:

```
result = set1 - set2
```

Which prints:

```
{'cat'}
```

You can convert it to a list or a string:

```
result_as_list = list(result)
result_as_string = ','.join(result)
```

Comment: This solution works as long as input string values are unique (within one string).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you are gonna do it. The function defined here will print the difference between the two lists

```
def Diff(list1, list2):
    li_dif = [i for i in list1 + list2 if i not in list1 or i not in list2]
    return li_dif
 
# Driver Code
list1 = ['cat','dog','whale','hamster']
list2 = ['dog','whale','hamster']
diff = Diff(list1, list2)
print(diff)
```

output:

```
['cat']
```

here `cat` is generated by the variable `diff`

Now if there is more than one difference, as follows:

```
def Diff(list1, list2):
    li_dif = [i for i in list1 + list2 if i not in list1 or i not in list2]
    return li_dif
 
# Driver Code
list1 = ['cat','dog','whale','hamster','ostrich','yak','sheep','lion','tiger']
list2 = ['dog','whale','hamster']
diff = Diff(list1, list2)
print(diff)
```

the output will be:

```
['cat','ostrich','yak','sheep','lion','tiger']
```

Your question is that if there is more than one difference, each of these differences should be assigned to an individual variable.
for that, we will treat the printed item as a list, let's name it `list3`

`diff==list3`
here, `list3=['cat','ostrich','yak','sheep','lion','tiger']`

Here, is only 6 list items, we can assign a variable to each of them as follows:

```
    v1=list3[0]
    v2=list3[1]
    v3=list3[2]
    v4=list3[3]
    v5=list3[4]
    v6=list3[5]
```